# How to fill ListBox from a List with DelegateCommand in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, viewmodel, delegatecommand

I faced a problem while trying to fill my ListBox.
I have a button in my xaml file:

```
<Button Content="Show" Command="{Binding ShowSongsBy}" ... >
```

I also have a ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="sorted" ItemsSource="{Binding SortedListVM}" ... >
```

In my ViewModel I have:

```
        private List<string> _sortedList;
        public List<string> SortedListVM
        {
            set
            {
                _sortedList = value;
                onPropertyChanged();
            }
            get { return _sortedList; }
        }
```

and

```
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void onPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
```

When I press the button, this is what happens (also in ViewModel):

```
public ICommand ShowSongsBy
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegateCommand((obj) =>
                {
                    SortedListVM = new List<string>();

                    List<string> testlist = new List<string>();
                    testlist.Add("1");
                    testlist.Add("2");

                    foreach (string i in testlist)
                    {
                        SortedListVM.Add(i);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

What I expect to see in the ListBox: "1" and "2". What I see instead: just "1"

I can't figure out what's the problem.
Also if I change the code to this:

```
public ICommand ShowSongsBy
{
...
                    foreach (string i in testlist)
                    {
                        SortedListVM.Add(i);
                    }

                    SortedListVM.Add("Test1");
...
```

I see what I expect to see in the ListBox: "1", "2" and "Test1".

What do I do if I only want "1" and "2" to be listed?

My DelegateCommand class:

```
class DelegateCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> execute;
        private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.execute(parameter);
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`.

```csharp
private ObservableCollection<string> _sortedList;
public ObservableCollection<string> SortedListVM
{
    get => _sortedList;
    set
    {
        _sortedList = value;
        onPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

... and do what you want to do with it. In the same way as you operate with `List`.

`ListBox` will dynamically update its layout when you'll make any changes to the collection.